# What should I do when I do not get a reply to an email?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, communication

I have sent out emails enquiring about academic positions in departments active in my field. I did my best to write them properly, consulting websites and more experienced academics.

However, it has been a week since I sent them, and have not heard back.

Should I do something? Or wait?

Clarifications:
I am in Zoology, and have enquired about potential applications.

Comment: Something is not clear: did you apply for academic positions and you haven;t received any answer? Or you just made inquiries about potential applications? If it's the latter, I am afraid there is not much you can do.

Comment: You are right, I should clarify. I made inquiries about potential applications.

Answer (score 2):

This differs hugely by field and country, but in mine you don't contact the professors directly. If positions are available, then they will be advertised. Now you need inside/national knowledge where these positions will be advertised, but typically they will also appear on the website besides the "normal" venue.

Imagine how many people are looking for a job. A prof would not be able to do her job if she had to answer all the job enquiries, so they are typically just ignored. This is not very nice, bit an understandable strategy of dealing with too many e-mails.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I am targeting the UK, from outside the UK, and I am not certain about the proper etiquette for these communications. On their websites, the departments I have contacted state that they welcome inquiries from potential fellowship applicants. In my emails I state that I am keen on securing funding for postdoctoral studies, but also looking for interim research assistant positions etc. Is this perhaps too much to ask?

Comment: @Isovitis It would help us to know what field are you talking about. In my field, TCS, all communications are done directly with the PI!

Comment: Right - I am in Zoology, and specifically animal biomechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Most good departments receive a lot of unsolicited mail with job inquiries. The harsh truth is that you are not very likely to get a positive reply by just cold-writing senior staff, even if your academic credentials are very good.

Find adverts and respond to those instead. When you do so, make sure to tailor your response to the department, rather than to send out a standard application.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solid advice. I have been researching each department and adjusting my letters to their activities. Is there a chance that my unsolicited inquiries may be viewed negatively, and impact any future interactions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with writing to the head of a research group, you can always try that. I'm working in a biology-related field and sometimes a sudden demand for a person to analyze some samples or to go on a field trip comes up. Though this would likely be a short term position (and often is given to people known to the research group already) you might just be lucky enough to have offered your services at the right time.

This works of course best if you are looking for some "loose" contract (some part time job for a couple of months or even an internship) and if you are already around (meaning the employer does not have any responsibility to arrange for travel and accommodation). I've taken pretty much this same route, first doing an internship, afterwards a part time job and now I have a contract.

Regarding the issue that you haven't heard back yet: I would wait a little longer, at least a week, possibly a month (also because in the meantime some little job may have opened up). Afterwards write a short and friendly reminder. You might also want to encourage them to forward your email and CV to some interested colleague. If you don't hear back still, I'd forget about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This is very encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

First note that a week is not enough time to conclude that someone/some group is not going to answer you (unless there's some known deadline that's closer than a month away of which both you and your addressee are aware of, or unless you asked for an immediate reply and gave a good reason). So you have to wait a while longer. Sorry, I know this is stressful :-(

Anyway, another week or so,

1. Try phone calls instead of a second email. Either call the person you wrote or a secretariat of some kind; if you do the latter, of course, you're not reminding them of anything or complaining, you're just making the same inquiry except over the phone. If they tell you "You should email `important.prof@somewhere.edu`" then you tell them "oh, but I did email him/her a week ago and didn't get an answer. Is he/her traveling?" etc.

   These days you could use phone software which offers local-fare calls by taking the call over IP to the target country first. (Sorry to have to plug Microsoft, but Skype does this.) That makes it cheaper than a plain vanilla international phonecall.
2. If 1. doesn't work, try a reminder email (be very polite and don't intimate any dissatisfaction from not having been answered more quickly).
3. If 2. doesn't work, try writing/calling other people at the same research group who are not the people who should be answering you, tell them that "I've written Important Person about [...] but have not received a reply [...] so I was hoping you could [...]"